# Verifying simple-php-captcha() input

Tags: php, variables, captcha, verification

The POST form works fine and all the data is submitted properly, `$captcha_code` is returning the correct output and so is `$captcha`. However, when I check if `$captcha == $captcha_code` it always returns failure. Can someone please explain as to why this happens?

```
include 'inc/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php';
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
$captcha_code = $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
  $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

  if($captcha == $captcha_code) {
    echo 'captcha success';
  } else {
    echo 'captcha failure';
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `echo var_dump($captcha." = ".$captcha_code);` to debug the variable

Comment: You were generated a new captcha from this `$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();` You must get the last captcha from last page not generated again

Comment: What is your last page? Form page, please post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the captcha before itself in login.php

*login-form.php*

```
<?php
// start session and generate captcha and it's image
session_start();
include 'inc/simple-php-captcha/simple-php-captcha.php';
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();

// render the form
?>

<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="password">
..
..
<input type="text" name="captcha">
<img src="<?php $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']; ?>">
<input type="submit">
```

*login-submit.php*

```
$captcha_code = $_SESSION['captcha']['code']; //retrive what code was generated before

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
  $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

  if($captcha == $captcha_code) {    // try matching
    echo 'captcha success';
  } else {
    echo 'capture failure';
  }
}
```